# how to hide two forms and when a user selects a contact form only this one appears

Tags: jquery, forms, hide, show

I am trying to use jQuery to hide my two forms (contact, & project planner) on load of page, but when a user clicks on either, then that particular form appears. I'm unsure how to do this with jQuery. I've tried a few approaches with zero luck. Any help would be most appreciative.

```
<div id="contact_box_style">
                <div class="contact">
                    <a class="btn_choose" id="contact_form" href="#contact">
                        <h2>Contact Me</h2>             
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="contact">
                    <a class="btn_choose" id="project_planner" href="#booking">
                    <h2>Project Planner</h2>
                </div>
            </div><!--end of contact_box_style-->
        </div><!--end of options_container-->
        <div id="form_container">
            <div class="margin_setup">
                <div id="form_look_contact">
                    <form action="contact_process.php" id="contact" method="POST">
                        <h1 class="header_title">Contact</h1>
                        <div class="contact_item">
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="contact_name" placeholder="Your name" />                      
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact_item">
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="contact_email" placeholder="Your email" />                  
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact_item">
                            <input type="text" name="company" class="contact_company" placeholder="company" />                  
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact_item">
                            <input type="text" name="industry" class="contact_industry" placeholder="Industry" />                   
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact_item">
                            <textarea name="comment" class="contact-info" placeholder="Your comment"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button name="send" class="send" type="submit">Send</button> 
                    </form>
                </div><!--end of form_look-->
            </div><!--end of form_setup-->
        </div><!--end of form_container-->
    </div><!--end of section_margin_setup-->
    <div id="form_container">
            <div class="margin_setup">
                <div idf="orm_look_booking">
                    <form action="booking_process.php" id="booking" method="POST">
                        <h1 class="header_title">Project Planner</h1>
                        <div class="contact_item">
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="contact_name" placeholder="Your name" />                      
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact_item">
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="contact_email" placeholder="Your email" />                  
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact_item">
                            <input type="text" name="company" class="contact_company" placeholder="Company" />                  
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact_item">
                            <input type="text" name="website" class="contact_company" placeholder="Current Website: http://" />                 
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact_item">
                            <input type="text" name="industry" class="contact_industry" placeholder="Industry" />                   
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact_item">
                            <input type="text" name="budget" class="contact_bidgety" placeholder="Budget" />                    
                        </div>
                        <div id="check_box">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="CMS / BLOG" value="CMS" class="contact_company" />CMS                  
                            <input type="checkbox" name="E-Commerce" value="E-Commerce" class="contact_company" />E-Commerce
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Basic Website" value="Basic" class="contact_company" />Website
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Video Production" value="Video Production" class="contact_company" />Video Production
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Business Card Design" value="Business Card Design" class="contact_company" />Business Card Design
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact_item">
                            <textarea name="booking" class="booking_comment" placeholder="Any other information?"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button name="send" class="send" type="submit">Send</button> 
                    </form>
                </div><!--end of form_look-->
            </div><!--end of form_setup-->
        </div><!--end of form_container-->
    </div><!--end of section_margin_setup-->
</div><!--end wrapper_container-->
```

Comment: Both the forms have the same id, is it?

Comment: Yes, same ID is poor fundamentals.  However, you can give them a shared class with which to apply your jQuery event.

Comment: the form itself has two different id's, one id="contact" other id="booking" and the styling form <div id="form_look_contact"> is one and the other is <div id="form_look_booking"> so two different id's for different forms.

Comment: How does the user click on the form if it's hidden?

Comment: they will have an option to select contact or project planner. If you see at the top, there are two headings that aren't hidden etc. It's only the forms that are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Put both the forms in separate divs with separate ids and then manipulate visibility on clicks.

```
<input type = "button" id = "contact_btn" value = "Contact"/>
<input type = "button" id = "booking_btn" value = "Booking"/>
<div id = "contact_form_div" style = "display:none;">
.... form
</div>
<div id = "booking_form_div" style = "display:none;">
.... form
</div>
```

You javascript would be something like

```
$(document).on("click", "input#contact_btn", function() {
$("div#contact_form_div").show();
$("div#booking_form_div").hide();
}

$(document).on("click", "input#booking_btn", function() {
$("div#booking_form_div").show();
$("div#contact_form_div").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Hide both forms as soon as the document loads
    $('#contact').hide();
    $('#booking').hide();


    // when the user clicks on either of the "buttons", show the
    // appropriate div.
    $('#contact_form').click(function() {
        $('#contact').show();
    });

    $('#project_planner').click(function() {
        $('#booking').show();
    });

});
```

Although you really should think about renaming your ID's ... `contact_form` isn't a form -- It's something more like a button.

<sup>Note that I haven't tried this code.  I'm a little concerned that the anchor will swallow the event before it gets to jQuery ...</sup>

Comment: thank you I changed it slightly and used your code and adjusted it. Works fine. Thanks